# Check if certain data exists in a field in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table (tblForms) in which one of the fields is a lookup to another table (tblClients). How can I find if a certain Client has data or does not have data in tblForms? DCount only works if the Client does appear in tblForms.

I have a form (frmDisclosure) with a command button - onClick:

```
Private Sub Command245_Click()
On Error GoTo Command245_Click_Err

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmClient", acNormal, "", "[ClientID]= " & Me.Client, , acNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDisclosure"

Command245_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

Command245_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Command245_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

When I click this I get the error (N.B. I f I open frmClient directly form Switchboard I don't get the error). frmClient has a subform (continuous) frmFormsList which derives its data from:

```
SELECT tblForms.ClientLookup, tblForms.Issued, First(tblForms.RefNo) AS FirstOfRefNo, Last(tblForms.RefNo) AS LastOfRefNo, Count(tblForms.RefNo) AS CountOfRefNo, tblClient.KnownAs, tblClient.EMail
FROM tblForms INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblForms.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID
GROUP BY tblForms.ClientLookup, tblForms.Issued, tblClient.KnownAs, tblClient.EMail
HAVING (((tblForms.Issued) Is Not Null));
```

This function resides in frmFormsList:

```
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer

NumRecs = DCount("*", "tblForms", "ClientLookup = " & Me.ClientLookup)

End Function
```

My query shows data where I have issued forms to a client. Therefore if I have not issued forms to a Client tne the query shows nothing for that client so does not give a result 0. I get RunTime Error 2427 "You entered ans expression that has no value". NumRecs = DCount("*", "tblForms", "ClientLookup = " & Me.ClientLookup) is highlighted in debug.

In frm Disclosure, if I Rem out ", acNormal, "", "[ClientID]= " & Me.Client, , acNormal" the problem does not occur, but I don't get straight to the Client I am interested in. So the problem occurs when I try to open a form using the Rem'd out bit where the client has not been issued with any forms. When I opne the frm Client directly the rocord presented does not have forms issued but the problem does not occur.

Comment: Gibe some example, your description is very vague. If DCount is 0 then the client does not appear in the tblForms, so you have your answer, is that not right?

Comment: I have a form (frmDisclosure) with a command button - on click:        Private Sub Command245_Click()
    On Error GoTo Command245_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmClient", acNormal, "", "[ClientID]= " &Me.Client, , acNormal
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDisclosure"

Command245_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command245_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command245_Click_Exit

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:
    Public Function NumRecs() As Integer

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As Object

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset("qryDisclosure", dbOpenDynaset)

If Me.Recordset.RecordCount = 0 Then
    NumRecs = 0
Else
    NumRecs = Nz(DCount("*", "qryDisclosure", "ClientLookup = " &   Me.ClientLookup), 0)
End If
```

End Function